# T-SQL less than percentage - returns 100% even though excluded?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find all the rows for which the cell in column x (a percentage) is less than or equal to 80%.

So I have

Select 
...
from
...
where ColX_pc <= '80'.

Bizarrely, this returns all values which are less than or equal to 80%, and excludes all values which are either null or >80% but <100%.  However, it also returns all of the values which are 100%.  I am confused by this and assume that it's something to do with conversion?

**UPDATE - I realise what's causing this now - the column is varchar and hence 100% is regarded as "less than" 80%.**  The best solution was identified in the answer below.

Comment: So the `%` character is in the field, which is a character type? If so 
`'100%' < '80'` is true because you are comparing strings not integers ...

Comment: *"The addition of `and Colx <> '100.00%'`"* does not provide a solution.  It merely means you've suppressed the one symptom you've noticed.  String comparison is not a substitute for numeric comparison.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yes, correct.  See the answer below which outlines an effective solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you storing *numbers* as strings?  When you do, you get *string* comparison.  If you want to compare as numbers, then convert to numbers:

```
where try_convert(numeric(38, 6), replace(ColX_pc, '%', '')) <= 80
```

Using string comparison, `'100%'` is less than `'80%'` because `'1'` < `'8'`.

You are also missing `'9%'`, but you probably didn't notice.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  I identified this shortly after posting the answer and edited above.  I did not notice 9% though - good point.  I will mark this as the answer in a few minutes.